# problem with label css3dObjects and camera near from them

Tags: renderer

I have a problem with css3dRenderer,  when I aproach to a plane where I am projecting a txt label using css3dRenderer The label is cut.

Comment: here the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nuotpavz/

Comment: Here some screenshots:

Answer (score 0):

SOrry, I didn't know how to attach some screenshots in other way:

[image]

[image]